# Stripping Parentheses (and contents) out of URL's

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge database filled with scientific names that look like this:

```
Canis lupus
Homo sapiens
```

I replace the spaces with dashes to convert them to URL's...

```
Canis-lupus
Homo-sapiens
```

But there are a lot of scientific names that look like this:

```
Panthera (Felis) leo 
Allactaga (Allactaga) vinogradovi
```

Can anyone suggest the best method for stripping out 1) the parentheses, 2) the contents of the parentheses, and 3) any spaces before or after parentheses with a dash, so the output looks like this?:

```
Panthera-leo
```

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: something wrong with `urlencode()` ?

Comment: Url encode is a php function that does it for you, I'm on my phone on the can so I don't really feel like answering so here's the php function page, it's real easy to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Do you want to just replace that in SELECT results, or UPDATE the data directly in the table? If you can rely on there being only one set of parenthesis max, it is doable in a query; otherwise you are better off using a programming language.

Comment: Thx; I'll check out urlencode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT([field], INSTR([field], '(')-1)
              , '-'
              , SUBSTR([field], INSTR([field], ')')+1)
       ) AS innerTrimmedField
FROM [table]
WHERE [field] LIKE '%(%)%'
;
```

Note that you'll still need to deal with spaces. If the parenthesis had spaces before and/or after them, all those will now be adjacent to each other; so you'll need to deal with that as well, unless you don't mind `Panthera (Felis) leo` becoming `Panthera---leo`.

If you need a list of all the entries, you can UNION this with the non-parenthesis ones (using a `WHERE [field] NOT LIKE '%(%)%'` for those). If you made that `UNION` query a subquery, you could have an outer query take care of the space replacement for all of them at once.

But this will probably be faster and a little more flexible:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
        IF([field] LIKE '%(%)%'
           , CONCAT(LEFT([field], INSTR([field], '(')-1)
                    , '-'
                    , SUBSTR([field], INSTR([field], ')')+1)
                   )
           , [field]
          )
        , ' ', '-') AS normalizedStrings
FROM [table]
WHERE [standard filter conditions you might want]
;
```